# Rsync (3.2.7): log file does not contain [receiver] entries?

Tags: logging, rsync

I am using rsync 3.2.7 and set it to log to a file via `--log-file '/path/to/log.file'`. I use the log file to sniff for occurrences of "No space left on device" error messages. They are tagged as `[receiver]` messages. However, these entries ceased to show up in the log file, they are reported via `stderr`. (They used to show up before, was it 3.1.0, mmmh?)

For now, I am resorting to redirecting explicitly `stderr` to the same `/path/to/log.file`. But this seems strange to me. I played with `-v` or different `--info` flags, but this does not make the `[receiver]` messages appear in the log file.

Important: There is no `rsyncd` involved, I use `rsync` only locally.

Comment: This is `rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31` on macOS 13.3.1 obtained via MacPorts.